# R : how to Detect Pattern in Matrix By Row

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big matrix with 4 columns, containing normalized values (by column, mean ~ 0 and standard deviation = 1)

I would like to see if there is a pattern in the matrix, and if yes I would like to cluster rows by pattern, by pattern I mean values in a given row example

for row N

if value in column 1 < column 2 < column 3 < column 4 then it is let's say a pattern 1

Basically there is 4^4 = 256 possible patterns (in theory)

Is there a way in R to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Rad

Answer (score 2):

Yes. (Although the number of distinct permutations is only 24 = 4*3*2. After one value is chosen, there are only three possible second values, and after the second is specified there are only two more orderings left.) The `order` function applied to each row should give the desired 1,2,3, 4 permutations:

```
mtx <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=4)
res <- apply(mtx, 1, function(x) paste( order(x), collapse=".")  )

> table(res)[1:10]
> table(res)
res
1.2.3.4 1.2.4.3 1.3.2.4 1.3.4.2 1.4.2.3 1.4.3.2 
     98     112      95     120     114     118 
2.1.3.4 2.1.4.3 2.3.1.4 2.3.4.1 2.4.1.3 2.4.3.1 
    101     114     105     102     104     122 
3.1.2.4 3.1.4.2 3.2.1.4 3.2.4.1 3.4.1.2 3.4.2.1 
    105      82     107      90      97      86 
4.1.2.3 4.1.3.2 4.2.1.3 4.2.3.1 4.3.1.2 4.3.2.1 
     99      93     100     108     118     110
```

Comment: it's possible that column 1 = column 2, and so forth, so there are two possibilities for each of the three comparisons (> obviously doesn't need to be considered), giving 4*3*2*2^3=192 permutations, right? Or did I just have a brain fart?

Comment: Except the probability measure of those extra possibilities has measure zero when the numbers are on the real line. :-)

Comment: Sorry for a newbie comment but there is something I don't get in the result returned, according to table command description in R, it is like a clustering method, so the number returned under let's say 1.2.3.4 are the number of rows in the matrix having this pattern, my question is how to extract rows for a given pattern given this result ?

Comment: The result of table is a matrix (or in this case a named vector) with names that can be used as indices: `table(res)["1.2.3.4"]` returns 98 from the sample I had.

Comment: DWin, is it possible to modify the code so that to capture patterns like "1.1.1.1" or "1.1.3.4" etc ... meaning not limiting it at 24 ?